# A final class and underlying consequences in Java

Tags: java, stringbuilder, final

I heard this line somewhere and I cannot get it off of my mind:

"All members of a final class are implicitly final."

Now, I know very well these three famous concepts:

1. A `final` class cannot be extended.
2. A `final` variable cannot be re-assigned with a new value once initialized.
3. A `final` method cannot be overridden.

But, if all members (variables, methods) of a final class are implicitly final, then we have a final class AND final variables AND final methods in it.

Then, how is it possible that `StringBuilder`, despite being final, allows its contents to change?!

Comment: final doesn't mean immutable (see `ArrayList` for example)

Comment: Only the methods are final implicitly (since they could only be overridden by subclassing and subclassing is denied). The variables remain non-final unless marked.

Comment: You cant override any methods in the StringBuilder class, only its text -- content can be changed, note the difference.

Comment: Write some sample code and run it. Learn more that way besides just remebering and site online - teachers are not perfect if someone really said that. It atint true

Comment: @Dave: Yes, that must be it! No wonder why "final" and "mutable" are not mutually exclusive! That makes sense now. It has got to be only methods that essentially end up being final due to a final class they belong to. A class being final allows NO sub-classing, and without sub-classing there can be NO overriding of methods.

Comment: @RC: I don't understand what ArrayList exemplifies here. It is no-final and mutable.

Comment: @MohammadAliAsgar I meant you can add content to a final arraylist

Comment: @RC: Yes, you can add contents to a final instance of ArrayList. That is a different thing. You are making a reference variable final which points to an instance of ArrayList. But here we are talking about a whole class that is final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That assertion is oversimplified and therefore wrong.  Only *methods* of a `final` class can be considered implicitly `final`.  This fact is however irrelevant in itslef, as methods of a `final` class cannot be overriden because there can't be any subclasses.  It doesn't really matter if they're `final` or not, implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: how is it "not exactly true"?

Comment: @eis: It is, as far as I know, not stated in the Java Language Specification. But then, as I said, it's completely irrelevant, as the only difference between a final and non-final method is it being overridable.

Comment: well, either it is or it isn't. You shouldn't claim so if you think it isn't true, it's a bit hard to judge from the answer which side are you on. I agree on it being irrelevant though.

Comment: @eis, you're right, I've changed the wording to a more neutral one.

Answer (score 1):

A class can be final, but mutable.

The class being final just means there can be no subclasses, but says nothing about the behaviour of the class.

Conversely, fields and methods can be final (and the instances [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)), but the class not final.

Finality of a class and of class members are unrelated.

Comment: All the methods in a final class are implicitly final as well, and methods are also members of the class. Other than that I agree.